# Website is not secured when full url is entered manually?

Tags: php, reactjs, redirect, https

I have a React app on myapp.com which has SSL certificate installed.
When I enter myapp.com in the browser, it goes to https://myapp.com as expected. If I navigate to /shop from there, it's still secured.

But the problem is when I enter myapp.com/shop manually in the url. Then the connection is not secured.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the flags of the rewrite rule  `[R,L]`

Full code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Another best practice would be to change the `HTTPS` check with the port check, but this is optional as your code should work fine too.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```